# Pair Columns then ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

This HAS to be a PEBCAK problem as it seems so basic. Is there a query to say, "If 'mon' = 1 THEN ORDER BY 'time' THEN if 'tue' = 1 ORDER BY 'time', THEN if 'wed' = 1 ORDER BY 'time'" ?

```
+=====+=====+=====+========+
| mon | tue | wed |  time  |
+=====+=====+=====+========+
|  0  |  1  |  1  |  0100  |
|  0  |  0  |  0  |  2200  |
|  1  |  1  |  1  |  1500  |
|  1  |  1  |  0  |  0600  |
|  0  |  0  |  0  |  1400  |
|  1  |  0  |  1  |  1100  |
+=====+=====+=====+========+
```

Desired result:

```
mon 0600
mon 1100
mon 1500
tue 0100
tue 0600
tue 1500
wed 0100
wed 1100
wed 1500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
ORDER BY CASE WHEN mon=1 THEN 1 WHEN tue=1 THEN 2 WHEN wed=1 THEN 3 END,
    time
```